# sed: remove all matches in the file and insert some lines where the first match was

Tags: text-processing, sed, configuration, ntpd

Say I want to automatically update my `/etc/ntp.conf` configuration using `sed`. Format of `ntp.conf` allows to define *lists* by usage same keywords for lines occurred all over the file. For example:

```
# first block occurrences
server 1.1.1.1
server 2.2.2.2

driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift

# second block of occurrences
server 3.3.3.3
server 4.4.4.4
```

Now, I've got updated list of `ntp` servers, say 5.5.5.5, 6.6.6.6 and 7.7.7.7. As a result I want to get:

```
# first block occurrences
server 5.5.5.5
server 6.6.6.6
server 7.7.7.7

driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift

# second block of occurrences
```

Can I do it with `sed`? Is it right tool for this problem or should I use something else?

P.S.: commenting out second block (or both) of occurrences could also be an option.

Comment: Do you need those two distinct blocks, or could `sed` delete all such lines and then simply append the new ones?

Comment: Append new lines to the end of file would be trivial solution. But it's desirable for me to put new lines in place of first block because I want to keep automatically updated values close to related comment blocks in configuration files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the new list of servers in a file named `list.txt` in `cwd`:

```
sed '/^server/{x;//!r list.txt
d}' /etc/ntp.conf
```

or, if you don't want to use a file but rather hardcode the new server names:

```
sed '/^server/{x;//!c\
server 1\
........\
server n-1\
server n
d}' /etc/ntp.conf
```

This assumes that *there is at least one non-commented* `server` *line* in your `/etc/ntp.conf` (also, it will not remove any `server` lines that are commented out - you can change the regex to include those too). If you wanted to insert those lines even if there were no server entries in original file (and in that case, add the new servers at the end of file) you could do something like:

```
sed '/^server/{x;//!r list.txt
d}
${x;//!r list.txt
x}' /etc/ntp.conf
```

or use the same conditions if you prefer using `c\` - I'll leave that as an exercise. Keep in mind that when changing lines with `c\` all backslashes and embedded newlines have to be escaped with a backslash (as in my example).

Comment: Sure, if you wanted to edit the file in-place you'd use `sed -i ...`

Comment: Is it possible to make sed expression also handling case when there is no server entries in original file (i.e. adding new servers at the end)?

Comment: @reddot - yes, that's not a problem, see my edit

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '
/^server/ d
/first block/a\
server 5.5.5.5\
server 6.6.6.6\
server 7.7.7.7
' /etc/ntp.conf
```

change the first occurence only:

```
# first block occurrences
server 5.5.5.5
server 6.6.6.6
server 7.7.7.7

driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift

# second block of occurrences
```

Comment: This solution looks nice and readable but relying on comment text is not good.